# trying to delete an app found in 'system information' but it wont delete

Tags: applications, catalina, storage, macos

I'm trying to free up some space. From the apple icon in the top left corner I went into 'about this mac'. from there I went to storage, and then clicked 'manage'. In the applications part the app at the top is a game called 'Dota 2' - 23.42 GB but it's not anywhere when i search in find nor if I follow the pathway at the bottom (User->library->application support->steam->games etc).

Is this game on my computer or is it a glitch? It doesn't do anything but freeze for a second when I hit delete in 'System Information'.

thanks if anyone knows something of this nature

[image: About this mac storage]

[image: Applications in System Information]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it was part of the Steam app. You need to remove it from there. In the end it was not fully downloaded so it didn't take up 20+ GB but only a few MB. So I guess this estimation is not always entirely accurate. Stay safe everyone